# Replace externally called callbacks with RxJava

Tags: android, callback, kotlin, rx-java, google-vision

I have an application using Google Mobile Vision, where the detector's `detect(Frame frame)` method is called externally by the framework. In that method I call callbacks of the hosting `Activity`:

```
override fun detect(frame: Frame?): SparseArray<Barcode> {
    ...
    activity.doSomethingOn(theDetections)
}
```

Due to reactive nature of the logic, I would like to introduce ReactiveX in as many places as possible, and replace callbacks with creating a stream. Is it possible at all? Following does not work:

```
val detections: Flowable<SparseArray<Barcode>> = SparseArray<Barcode>()
    .toSingle()
    .toFlowable()

override fun detect(frame: Frame?): SparseArray<Barcode> {
    ...
    detections.concatWith(detections.toSingle().toFlowable())
}
```

and in activity this is not called at all:

```
detector.detections
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .forEach { info(detections.size) }
```

This does not work either:

```
val detections: Flowable<SparseArray<Barcode>> = SparseArray<Barcode>()
    .toSingle()
    .toFlowable()

fun lastDetections(): Flowable<SparseArray<Barcode>> = detections

override fun detect(frame: Frame?): SparseArray<Barcode> {
    ...
    detections.concatWith(detections.toSingle().toFlowable())
    lastDetections()
}
```

and in activity:

```
detector.lastDetections()
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .forEach { info(detections.size) }
```

What do I do wrongly? Is such replacement possible at all? Does it - above all - make sense? (I would say "yes").

Comment: Where do you subscribe?

Comment: in `onResume`. I will try subscribing near properties declaration

Comment: ok, that was impossible due to `Context` being not yet fed to the detector. Moving subscription to `onCreate` did not change anything

Comment: I just stumbled upon https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde5831 and will try to implement this tomorrow

Comment: sadly project has been abandoned since, and I don't know if we're gonna get back to it. I'm afraid I won't try that solution before New Year.